# AppEngine JDO query is not working as expected

Tags: java, google-app-engine, jdo

I'm working with AppEngine and I want to query data entity with:

- Bool data 'optional' is False.
- ascending order for Date 'registrationTimestamp'.

My code:

```
Query query = pm.newQuery(DeviceInfo.class);
query.setFilter("optional == False");
query.setOrdering("registrationTimestamp asc");
List<DeviceInfo> datas = (List<DeviceInfo>)query.execute();
```

When I see datas, there are data with 'optional' is True. I want to filter-out entry which 'optional' is True. It seems setFilter("optional == False") is not working.

How can I perform query I want?

**EDIT**

I got log with DEBUG level which is advised by DataNucleus.

```
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: Bundle "org.datanucleus.jpa" has an optional dependency to "org.datanucleus.enhancer" but it cannot be resolved
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: Bundle "org.datanucleus" has an optional dependency to "org.eclipse.equinox.registry" but it cannot be resolved
org.datanucleus.plugin.NonManagedPluginRegistry resolveConstraints: Bundle "org.datanucleus" has an optional dependency to "org.eclipse.core.runtime" but it cannot be resolved
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property datanucleus.rdbms.sql.allowAllSQLStatements unknown - will be ignored
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property datanucleus.rdbms.stringDefaultLength unknown - will be ignored
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property datanucleus.appengine.autoCreateDatastoreTxns unknown - will be ignored
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl logConfiguration: ================= Persistence Configuration ===============
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl logConfiguration: DataNucleus Persistence Factory - Vendor: "DataNucleus"  Version: "1.1.5"
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl logConfiguration: DataNucleus Persistence Factory initialised for datastore URL="appengine" driver="" userName=""
org.datanucleus.ObjectManagerFactoryImpl logConfiguration: ===========================================================
org.datanucleus.PersistenceConfiguration setProperty: Property datanucleus.query.cached unknown - will be ignored
org.datanucleus.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager <init>: Registering listener for metadata initialisation
org.datanucleus.jdo.metadata.JDOAnnotationReader processClassAnnotations: Class "net.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.server.DeviceInfo" has been specified with JDO annotations so using those.
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.MetaDataValidator validate: Performing appengine-specific metadata validation for net.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.server.DeviceInfo
org.datanucleus.store.appengine.MetaDataValidator validate: Finished performing appengine-specific metadata validation for net.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx.server.DeviceInfo
org.datanucleus.store.StoreDataManager registerStoreData: Managing Persistence of Class : net.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.server.DeviceInfo [Table : <class name="DeviceInfo"
       identity-type="application"
       objectid-class="javax.jdo.identity.ObjectIdentity"
       persistence-modifier="persistence-capable"
>
<inheritance strategy="new-table">
</inheritance>
<field name="deviceRegistrationID"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true"
       unique="false">
</field>
<field name="gcm"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true"
       unique="false">
</field>
<field name="key"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       primary-key="true"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="false"
       unique="false">
</field>
<field name="optional"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true"
       unique="false">
</field>
<field name="registrationTimestamp"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true"
       unique="false">
</field>
</class>
, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]
org.datanucleus.store.StoreDataManager registerStoreData: Managing Persistence of Class : net.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.server.DeviceInfo [Table : <class name="DeviceInfo"
       identity-type="application"
       objectid-class="javax.jdo.identity.ObjectIdentity"
       persistence-modifier="persistence-capable"
>
<inheritance strategy="new-table">
</inheritance>
<field name="deviceRegistrationID"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true"
       unique="false">
</field>
<field name="gcm"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true"
       unique="false">
</field>
<field name="key"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       primary-key="true"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="false"
       unique="false">
</field>
<field name="optional"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true"
       unique="false">
</field>
<field name="registrationTimestamp"
       persistence-modifier="persistent"
       null-value="none"
       default-fetch-group="true"
       embedded="true"
       unique="false">
</field>
</class>
, InheritanceStrategy : new-table]
org.datanucleus.jdo.metadata.JDOMetaDataManager$MetaDataRegisterClassListener registerClass: Listener found initialisation for persistable class net.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxxx.server.DeviceInfo
com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl logChunkSizeWarning: This query does not have a chunk size set in FetchOptions and has returned over 1000 results.  If result sets of this size are common for this query, consider setting a chunk size to improve performance.
  To disable this warning set the following system property in appengine-web.xml (the value of the property doesn't matter): 'appengine.datastore.disableChunkSizeWarning'
```

Comment: and the log says what about the query?

Comment: @DataNucleus, I got exception for index not found when setFilter or setOrdering are not accepted. But with query shown in the question, I don't get exception, no error log. But I really see "optional == True" data in query result. So I think setFilter is not working.

Comment: the log tells you what low level query is used.

Comment: @DataNucleus, Log said:com.google.appengine.api.datastore.QueryResultsSourceImpl 
logChunkSizeWarning: This query does not have a chunk size set in FetchOptions and has returned over 1000 results.
If result sets of this size are common for this query, consider setting a chunk size to improve performance.
To disable this warning set the following system property in appengine-web.xml
(the value of the property doesn't matter): 'appengine.datastore.disableChunkSizeWarning'   But no query info.

Comment: when I'm debugging I show the log at DEBUG level

Comment: @DataNucleus, I added --debug but log did not come out more. I doubt --debug option did not work. I don't know why.

Comment: what is "--debug" to do with log4j/java.util.logging ? YOu need to read up on basic java logging libraries and how to enable DEBUG

Comment: @DataNucleus, Yes I read and managed to get what you are interested. I edited my question. Please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

though the direct hack

```
optional = false
```

should work, you should consider adding filters properly as per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Filters)

```
Query q = new Query("DeviceInfo")
            .addFilter("optional",
                       Query.FilterOperator.EQUAL,
                       false);
```

hope it helps

Comment: what you provided is low level DataStore API. I'd like to use JDO instead.